# URM computable indicating RAM computability

Tags: logic, incompleteness

How can we show that every URM computable function is RAM computable?

I can see that that from Church's thesis, URM Computability iff p.r., but now sure how to get this claim above.

Taking the hint below:

We need to show that what S(), T(), and J() means in the two state machines above.

Comment: What are the definitions? What have you tried?

Comment: URM computable function is iff being primitive recursive, and it is of essence to use the Successor, zero, and projection formula

Comment: What definitions are you using for URM and RAM?

Comment: What textbook are you using? This is a standard theorem that is proved in many books. Because of small variations in definitions from one book to another it may be easier to just read the proof in your book.

Comment: Generally the way show such a thing is to show that each machine model can emulate all the primitive operations of the other.

Comment: I am using Cutland computability but they dont talk about this. Can someone put a proof here? Thanks

Comment: "URM computable function is iff being primitive recursive". Not so. A function can be URM computable without being primitive recursive.

Comment: How can we prove this one then? @PeterSmith, can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

David Marker's notes http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math502-03/mm6-9.pdf pp. 45-46 will give you the materials for this. Marker proves the direction RAM computability $\Rightarrow$ URM computability (Exercise 6.18); but the same materials prove the reverse direction (Exercise 6.19).

Comment: I took a look at that, but dont see how to do the reverse direction, can you please explain?